# spring boot controller null multipartfile list request part

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, multipartform-data

updating spring-boot from 2.3.7 to 2.4.6 and encountering NPE issue with requestPart in rest controller. Essentially in 2.3.7 the list of multipartfiles was initialising as an empty list. And with 2.4.6 the list is now a null object. not sure if it's a legitimate change in function or a bug? or possible issue with our code?

```
  public Callable<ResponseEntity<EmailResponse>> process(
  @RequestHeader final HttpHeaders requestHeaders,
  @RequestPart(name = "email") @Valid EmailRequest email,
  @RequestPart(name = "attachments", required = false) List<MultipartFile> attachments,
  final HttpServletRequest request) {
...
}
```

Comment: AFAIK this has been part of an effort to better distinguish between a parameter not being send (making it `null`) or the parameter being empty (leading to an empty collection). But I cannot find the commit in Spring itself (not Spring Boot) that entails that.

Comment: possibly this then from what you are saying. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/83bfee92011575acc35812cc51f5f07bb544372b#diff-190a456f00d374b9ce0bab4bcdaae21095409b79c250f75a0e7b5f311138fb8e

i wonder if there is a nice way to work around it as empty list is much nicer to handle than null

Comment: But a lot harder to determine if it wasn't submitted or was empty. You could wrap it in an `Optional`, then remove `required` and use `Optional.map` instead of directly accessing the list. You might want to send a request to be able to set a default value for `@RequestPart` just like as with `@RequestParameter`.